# Barra de Progresso semelhante ao youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, progress-bar

Alguém tem alguma noção de como fazer uma barra de progresso semelhante ao do youtube com o carregamento de acordo com o tempo da página requisitada?

Comment: http://usabilitypost.com/2013/08/19/new-ui-pattern-website-loading-bars/ se for essa tem ai o pacote já desenvolvido: https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress